# Redirecionamento por link não está funcionando no Firefox

Tags: javascript, link

Bom, estou na reta final do desenvolvimento de um site, e surgiu um problema com o `browser` `Firefox`, em todos os outros `browsers` testados, um `link` dentro de um botão funcionou, porém, no `firefox`, ele lê o botão de cancelar/voltar como um botão de `submit`, mas ele está lá apenas como um simples `type="button"`

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de que com `javascript` ou `Jquery`, eu possa resolver o problema.

*Browsers testados [Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari Windows, Safari IOS, IE9+]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, quando seu #form receber um submit, você desabilita-o e realiza a sua ação, que no caso seria voltar/cancelar.

Com esse `return  false;` o submit não terá mais ação alguma.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    // sua ação.
    return false;
});
```

Abraços! =)

Comment: mas não quero desabilitar o submit, quero apenas que o botão de voltar aja como link, por exemplo, se o usuário se confundiu com a página, preencheu algumas informações, ele poderia voltar para ir à página desejada, testei a função, e ela desabilitou o botão de submit mas não o de voltar

Comment: Entendi. Um outro método pra fazer um botão de "voltar" seria sem o `type="button"` e o botão em um "a" modelado com CSS. Por exemplo: `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" class="btn-voltar">Voltar</a>`

Comment: fiz isso mas não funciona, o botão ta lendo como submit